# multiple expressions for single condition result

Tags: jsf-2, el

I have to change the header string of primefaces dialog, acording to a variable state in my backing bean. The condition would be the following (pseudo code):

```
#{backingBean.editing ? resourceBundle.edit_string resourceBundle.item.id : msg.add_string}
```

and the short snippet example:

```
<p:dialog id="dokDialog" header="#{backingBean.editing ? resourceBundle.edit_string resourceBundle.item.id : msg.add_string}" ...>
   <!-- content -->
</p:dialog>
```

In this example I want to display either value `#{msg.edit_string} #{resourceBundle.item.id}` or `#{msg.add_string}` according to boolean value of `#{backingBean.editing}`.

What I want to do is to show either `Editing Item 01` or `New Item` in the title.

Also I get the following exeption because I have two expressions (**resourceBundle.edit_string resourceBundle.item.id**) for one result:

```
Caused by: org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " <IDENTIFIER>
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you try this `#{backingBean.editing ? resourceBundle.edit_string : msg.add_string}` ?

Comment: Can you try same way without adding `#{}` to inner expression?

Comment: Yes that way works if I have one expression for each condition result. But i have two for first result `resourceBundle.edit_string resourceBundle.item.id`

Comment: resourceBundle.edit_string resourceBundle.item.id - it's a wrong expression. You need to concatenate

Comment: String.concat may help if you are using an appropriate version of EL: resourceBundle.edit_string.concat(' ').concat(resourceBundle.item.id

Comment: @Multisync that's exactly what I need please respond with an answer so I can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resourceBundle.edit_string resourceBundle.item.id` - it's a wrong expression. You need to concatenate

String.concat may help if you are using an appropriate version of EL: `resourceBundle.edit_string.concat(' ').concat(resourceBundle.item.id)`